# In a coxeter group, if $s_1\dots s_n=t_1\dots t_n$ then $t_1s_1\cdots s_r=s_1\cdots s_{r+1}$?

Tags: group-theory, coxeter-groups

Suppose you have two reduced expressions $s_1\dots s_n=t_1\dots t_n$ in a Coxeter group. If $r$ is the maximum index such that $t_1s_1\dots s_r$ is reduced, why does $t_1s_1\cdots s_r=s_1\dots s_{r+1}$? A paper I'm reading says it follows from the exchange rule.

I see that $t_1s_1\dots s_r=t_2\dots t_ns_n\dots s_{r+1}$, so by the deletion condition I should be able to deleter $2n-r+1$ terms from the right, but I don't see what that should be equal to $s_1\dots s_{r+1}$. In what way is the exchange condition being used here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $t_1s_1\ldots s_{r+1}$ is not reduced, we have
$$
  \ell(t_1s_1\ldots s_{r+1})\leq r<\ell(s_1\ldots s_{r+1}).
$$
The strong exchange condition then ensures
$$
  t_1s_1\ldots s_{r+1}=s_1s_2\ldots\hat s_i\ldots s_{r+1}
$$
for some $i$ with $1\leq i\leq r+1$. If $i<r+1$ then we would have
$$
  \ell(t_1s_1\ldots s_r)=\ell(s_1\ldots\hat s_i\ldots s_r)<r,
$$
contradicting the assumption that $t_1s_1\ldots s_r$ is reduced. Thus $i=r+1$, so
$$
  t_1s_1\ldots s_{r+1}=s_1s_2\ldots s_r.
$$